# Get objects labels from array and set to aria-label

Tags: javascript, html

I have my code like this.

```html
<div class="image">
    <a href="{{pagePath}}" aria-label="Published on {{date}} - Related tags are {{pageTags}}">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="date-and-tags">
    <div class="date">
        <span>{{date}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tags">
        {{#each pageTags}}
            <span class="tag">{{this.label}}</span>
        {{/each}}

    </div>
</div>
```

aria-label value is being rendered as - "Published on 18 Nov 2020 - Related tags are [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

is there any way to get each object label and put it as comma separated string in aria-label?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an array of objects as a string.

You need to convert the array of objects to a string and store it as a variable.

So in your JS you need to loop over your objects and then build a string, something like:

```
var pageTagsAsString = "";
for(var x = 0; x < pageTags.length; x++){
   pageTagsAsString += pageTags[x].label + ",";
}
pageTagsAsString = pageTagsAsString.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, ""); // remove trailing / leading commas
```

Then just use it like any other variable.

`<a href="{{pagePath}}" aria-label="Published on {{date}} - Related tags are {{pageTagsAsString}}">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this approach, value of pageTagsAsString is populated through JS, However If I refer the same variable in HTML, it's not being rendered. May be I need to get aria-label attribute from JS and update the value in JS itself? or any other approach? Please suggest! Thanks again.

Comment: What are you using for templating? Handlebars, moustache etc? If you want to put a fiddle together of how you are populating the page I will adjust it so it works for you.

Comment: We are using Handlebars

Comment: put a fiddle together so I can see how you are referencing / constructing items. Normally you would use `context = {pageTagsAsStringInTheBrowser: pageTagsAsStringVariabileInYourJS}` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringfy `pageTags` using `JSON.stringfy`

```
<a href="{{pagePath}}" aria-label="Published on {{date}} - Related tags are {JSON.stringify(pageTags)}">
```

You'll be able to do more string manipulations on it via `JSON.stringfy(...)` API in case you would like to adjust the string.

Comment: This would create a string with curly braces, commas, double quotes etc. `aria-label` needs a human readable string to make any sense to a screen reader user.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, I agree. This why I also added the part where you can apply additional string manipulations on the string. It's difficult to provide the most accurate solution when we don't have the full content/info of `pageTags`.

Comment: @Shimi Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work and it was rendered as string instead. For your information, each object in my scenario contains name, value pair. Example - 
{label: "test tag", value: "test-tag"}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using `{{#each pageTags}}`